# Integral constant too large C# when converting number

Tags: c#

I am working on a basic idle game (based on cookie clicker), and have a script to convert those larger numbers into smaller numbers using the code:

```
if(valueToConvert >= 1000000000000000000000) {
        converted = (valueToConvert/1000000000000000000000).ToString("f3") + "Sex";
```

However the 'integral constant' is too large,  I was wonder how get through this.

If you don't understand the code, it is checking if the users currency is larger than sextillion, and if so, set the number 1000000000000000000000 to  1 Sextillion.

Comment: What is confusing you about the error?  Your constant is _too large_.  You likely want to look at the [BigInteger Structure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @maccettura Read the question..."I was wonder how get through this". He knows it's too large. He wants to know how he can make this work.

Comment: @maccettura I understand the error, I don't know how to get around the error, so I can still convert 1x10^21 into 1 sextillion

Comment: Could you maybe convert before it gets that large? ie at the Billions or Millions?

Comment: @Mattattack I linked the BigInteger Structure in my comment.  The numbers you are dealing with are larger than 64 bits, so neither int or long can handle them.

Comment: @HadleyPettigrew I already do all the conversions along the way, but it is after sextillion I have problems, I suppose I can look at reusing my previous conversions, thanks!

Comment: @Mattattack what type is `valueToConvert`?

Comment: @maccettura always a float

Comment: @maccettura You're confusing 32-bit integers with 32-bit floats. A float can store values up to ~3.4+38, which is quite a bit larger than the 1e21 value here.

Comment: @JoeWhite I think my comment was worded poorly, but your answer explains what I should have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're writing an integer constant, but it's about 100x larger than the largest primitive integer type can hold. (1E+21, as compared to ulong.MaxValue which is approximately 1.8E+19.)

But that's no problem - you mentioned in the comments that your value is actually a float. So use a float constant (`1000000000000000000000f` or `1e+21f`) instead of an integer constant (`1000000000000000000000`).

Or if you're really using double (which is usually a better idea than float), use `1000000000000000000000.0` or `1e+21`.

Answer (score 0):

Storing such large number is pointless because the resolution on the value to so course. Why not just scale the number to the billion or trillion level, what ever is your lowest displayed quantity.

A function like this can convert the scaled integer to a displayed value without the need to compare large constants. If you range is wide enough that a 64-bit integer does not suffice then you can just use a double instead. Either way you no longer have to evaluate large constant values.

```
    public string ConvertValue(Int64 Value)
    {
        string[] ValueNames = { "Billion", "Trillion" ... };
        int index;

        for (index = 0; index < ValueNames.GetLength(0); index++)
        {
            Int64 NewValue = Value / 1000;
            if (NewValue == 0)
            {
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                Value = NewValue;
            }
        }

        return Value.ToString() + ValueNames[index];
    }
```